# Crop a RasterLayer with a SpatialPolygonDataFrame

Tags: r, r-raster, spatial-data-frame

I have a raster grid I want to crop according to land borders of the world map provided by the data of the package 'maptools'. By doing some reasearch, I found that I have to use the `crop()` function and then the `mask()` function, but I get an error message.

Here is my code :

```
# load the worldmap SpatialPolygonDataFrame
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
ll=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
world<-spTransform(wrld_simpl, ll)
ext<-extent(-10.417,31.917,34.083,71.083)
# get only region covering europe 
world@bbox<-as.matrix(ext)


# create the origin in WGS84 CRS
ll = CRS("+init=epsg:4326") 
origin = SpatialPoints(cbind(7,40),ll) 
# create the raster grid 
grid = raster() 
# define extent and resolution
e = extent(5,18,40,50)
extent(grid)<-e
res(grid)=c(0.08,0.08) 
# fill the raster values
grid[] = runif(1:20250)

# crop the grid with worldmap to erase sea areas
test<-crop(grid,world)
rasterize(world,test)
Found 246 region(s) and 3768 polygon(s)
Error in if (x1a > rxmx) { : argument is of length zero
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crop does not crop to the country polygons as you would think. In fact, the `crop(grid, world)` does not really crop anything, as the extent of world is larger than the extent of grid. You can check that by plotting `test`. It's just the same as `grid`.

Instead, after `grid[] = runif(1:ncell(grid))` you could do:

```
# we're going to make 3 plots
par(mfrow=c(1,3))

# crop the Worldmap to grid 
worldcrop<-crop(world, grid)
plot(worldcrop)

# rasterize output, give cells value of NAME(seas are NA)
worldcropr = rasterize(worldcrop,grid, field='NAME', fun='first')
plot(worldcropr)

# mask random grid by worldcropr
gridmask = mask(x=grid, mask=worldcropr)
plot(gridmask)

# number of land pixels:
sum(!is.na(gridmask@data@values))

# number of sea pixels:
sum(is.na(gridmask@data@values))
```

I believe that's what you're after.
[image: cropped grid]